# Spring Boot + JPA: orphanRemoval does not work in @DataJpaTest

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, jpa

I am trying to delete notifications of a user, when a user is deleted by using `orphanRemoval`.
My approach works when I run the application, or in `@SpringBootTest` testclasses, but not in `@DataJpaTest` testclasses. I am using the default database configuration with H2.
I have the following 2 entities:

```kotlin
@Entity
data class User(
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        var id: UUID? = null
) {
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @OneToMany(
            orphanRemoval = true,
            mappedBy = "user"
    )
    val notifications: MutableSet<Notification> = mutableSetOf()
}

@Entity
data class Notification(
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        var id: UUID? = null
) {
    @ManyToOne
    var user: User? = null
}

interface UserRepository: JpaRepository<User, UUID>
interface NotificationRepository: JpaRepository<Notification, UUID>
```

A user can have multiple notifications, and if I delete the user, then I want to delete all notification.

However, when I try to delete a user that has one or more notifications in a testclass that is annotated with `@DataJpaTest`, then the notifications are not deleted and a `ConstraintViolationException` is thrown.

When the same testcase is run in a testclass annotated with `@SpringBootTest`, then it works.

Implementation of testcases reproducing my issues:

```kotlin
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@SpringBootTest
class WithSpringBootTest {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var notificationRepository: NotificationRepository

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var userRepository: UserRepository

    @Test
    fun `validate that orphan removal works`() {
        Common.test(notificationRepository, userRepository)
    }
}


@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@DataJpaTest
class WithDataJpaTest {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var notificationRepository: NotificationRepository

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var userRepository: UserRepository

    @Test
    fun `validate that orphan removal works`() {
        Common.test(notificationRepository, userRepository)
    }
}

private class Common {
    companion object {
        fun test(
                notificationRepository: NotificationRepository,
                userRepository: UserRepository
                ) {
            notificationRepository.deleteAll()
            notificationRepository.flush()
            userRepository.deleteAll()
            userRepository.flush()

            val user = userRepository.saveAndFlush(User())
            val notification = Notification()
            notification.user = user
            notificationRepository.saveAndFlush(notification)

            userRepository.deleteById(user.id!!)
            userRepository.flush()
            notificationRepository.flush()
            Assert.assertTrue(notificationRepository.findAll().isEmpty())
        }
    }
}
```

I am wondering:

- why does that testcase fail in the testclass annotated with `@DataJpaTest`
- is there any way to work around that issue other than using `@SpringBootTest`
- are there any other annotations / annotation parameters that may not work in `@DataJpaTest` but will in `@SpringBootTest`?

Comment: Does it work when you also add `notification` to `User.notifications`? The key difference between `@SpringBootTest` and `@DataJpaTest` is that the former is not `@Transactional` by default. This means that, in the `@SpringBootTest` scenario, the `userRepository.deleteById(user.id!!)` line fetches a fresh `User` instance from the data store (meaning `User.notifications` gets re-populated), while the `@JpaDataTest` uses the original `user` that is still in the persistence context at that point, with `User.notifications` not properly populated

Comment: Hi @crizzis, thanks for your comment. Indeed the problem is that JPA does not ensure consistency at runtime.

Therefore, the user did not know of the notification in the transaction, and it was not deleted.

Without a transaction it works (like in SpringBootTest), or when adding the notification manually to the user.